# determine invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra

> $T: R^2 \rightarrow R^3$ defined by $T(a_1,a_2)=(3*a_1-a_2,a_2,4*a_1)$

It is not invertible because it has different dimensions, what's the justification for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the issue is slightly subtle.
$$
T: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 : T((x, y)) \equiv (3x - y, y, 4x) 
$$

Consider the function

$$
S: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 : S((p, q, r)) \equiv 
\big((p + q)/3, q\big)
$$

Let's now compute:

\begin{align*}
S \circ T &: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 \\
S(T(x, y)) &= S(p:3x-y, q: y, r: 4x) \\
&= ((p+q)/3: ((3x-y) + y)/3, q: y) \\
&= (x, y) = id 
\end{align*}

So $S \circ T = id$, which means that $S$ is a left inverse of $T$.

However:
\begin{align*}
T \circ S &: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow  \mathbb R^3 \\
T(S(p, q, r))& = T(x: (p+q)/3, y: q) \\
&= (3x-y: p+q-q, y : q, 4x: 4(p + q)/3) \\
&= (p, q, 4(p+q)/3)
\end{align*}

So $S$ fails to be a *right* inverse of $T$.

Now as for why this is the case, the proof relies on the fact that $T$ is not surjective. We can interpret the function $T$ as a linear map:

\begin{align*}
T((x, y)) \equiv (3x - y, y, 4x)
\end{align*}

$T$ is not surjective since, for example, the image of $T$ cannot contain point $(1, 0, 0)$, since this would need:

- The second coordinate $y = 0 $
- The third coordinate $4x = 0 , \implies x = 0$.
- The first coordinate, $3x - y = 3 \cdot 0 - 0 = 0 \neq 1$

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is invertible, there’s $L = T^{-1}$, which is linear (that’s not hard to prove) and clearly bijective. So $L$ is injective $\implies \ker L = \{(0,0,0)\}$. Now observe that $L(e_1), L(e_2), L(e_3)$ can’t be linearly independent because every linearly independent subset of $\mathbb R^2$ has no more than $\dim \mathbb R^2 = 2$ elements. So there are $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ s.t. $\sum_i \alpha_i L(e_i) = (0,0)$. Thus the kernel is nontrivial, a contradiction! Thus there’s no such $L$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T$ were invertible. So $T$ must be injective, so that $\ker(T)=\{(0,0)\}$, hence $\dim(\ker(T))=0$. Additionally, $T$ must be surjective, so that $\operatorname{im}(T)=\mathbb{R}^3$, which implies $\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))=3$. By the rank-nullity theorem, we require that:
$$2=\dim(\ker(T))+\dim(\operatorname{im}(T))$$
This is not the case by the above, hence $T$ cannot be invertible. Note that in theory a similar reasoning can be applied for any linear transformation between vector spaces $T:V\to W$ with finite $\dim(V)=m$ and $\dim(W)=n$ with $m\neq n$ and not just this specific one).